# Eigenvalues in unit disk for a 2x2 block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices

Consider the $2\times 2$ matrix
\begin{align*}
  Q = 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 \\ 
    0 & a
  \end{bmatrix}
  -
  \epsilon
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\ 
    1 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1-\epsilon & 1 \\ 
    -\epsilon & a
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
with $\epsilon>0$ and $a\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|a|<1$.

One can use the Jury criterion to conclude that there exists
a sufficiently small $\epsilon$ such that $Q$ has both the eigenvalues
in the open unit disk for all $|a|<1$.

I would like to extend this result to a block-wise case.
Consider the $2n \times 2n$ matrix
\begin{align}
\tag{1}
  X = 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    A & I \\ 
    0 & B
  \end{bmatrix}
  -
  \epsilon
  \begin{bmatrix}
    I & 0 \\ 
    C & 0
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    A-\epsilon I & I \\ 
    -\epsilon C & B
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
where $I \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is the identity matrix, $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ has the eigenvalues in the closed unit disk
(for simplicity, we may consider $A$ with a simple eigenvalue at $1$ and the other $n-1$ inside the open unit disk),
$B\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ has all the eigenvalues in the open unit disk,
$C\in \mathbb{R}$ is symmetric and positive semidefinite.

Can we choose $\epsilon>0$ sufficiently small such that $X$ has all the eigenvalues inside the unit disk?

Suppose that $B$ and $C$ commute, i.e., $BC=CB$, then they are jointly diagonalizable via a nonsingular matrix $T\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.
Therefore we can write
\begin{align}
\tag{2}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    T & 0 \\ 
    0 & T
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    A-\epsilon I & I \\ 
    -\epsilon C & B
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    T^{-1} & 0 \\ 
    0 & T^{-1}
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    T A T^{-1} -\epsilon I & I \\ 
    -\epsilon \Lambda_C & \Lambda_B
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

If also $T A T^{-1}$ were diagonal, then we can reduce the
problem to $n$ subproblems. I.e., by noticing that the eigenvalues of
\begin{align}
\tag{3}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    a & 0 & b & 0\\
    0 & c & 0 & d\\
    e & 0 & f & 0\\
    0 & g & 0 & h
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
are given by the union of the eigenvalues of
\begin{align*}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    e & f
  \end{bmatrix} \text{ and }
  \begin{bmatrix}
    c & d \\
    g & h
  \end{bmatrix},
\end{align*}
then we can study the eigenvalues of $n$ submatrices
in the form of $Q$.

Is it possible to manage the possibility that $T A T^{-1}$ is not diagonal? E.g. does there exist a closed form transformation that reduces the case (1) or (2) to the desired case (3)?

Comment: Crossposted https://mathoverflow.net/questions/393199/eigenvalues-in-unit-disk-for-a-2x2-block-matrix